# Layout Designer - Drag and Drop in PHP

Tags: php, layout, userscripts

I  would like to build a Layout designer in PHP or would like to use a readymade script( even if it is a paid one )

Basically I would like to create a sort of Layout where users could choose fields to add from a "field chooser". Each field could be of any type... and we would like to provide a field group too, where the user could  choose the number of columns, and make the columns of this "panel" droppable.

We should drag a field from a list, and drop the field to a placeholder on a Form (Panel?).
Finally, is it possible to "read" the form layout in order to store it for later use?

thanks

kabir

Comment: I built my.army.mil, what you are asking is a BIG question. You might want to break it into more than one question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a Drag and drop form/window designer for PHP - since 2007 [the Delphi PHP IDE](http://theopensourcery.com/phpdelphiphp.htm). It is now become part of the RADPHP X2 IDE available from [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/radphp). Both use the Delphi VCL framework.

Answer (score 1):

There is RADPHP from Embarcadero technologies. It uses vcl for php framework for visual design. You can drag & drop while designing the page. But the html code it produces is not compatible with w3 standards.

Comment: RADPHP is now called HTML5 Builder. Apart from being a php ide, it now has much more interesting features. For more details check out product site [HTML5 Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/html5-builder).

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop isn't available in PHP. PHP is a server-side language; what you're asking for in client-side and would be accomplished using something like JavaScript. You would then use PHP to read the user's choices based on an event occuring, i.e. an item dropped or the user click a confirmation button.

Comment: Well that depends there's GTK bindings for PHP that one could use if it were a desktop application.